# Where are the Direct Stock Purchases (DSP) sold?

Tags: stocks, india, shares

I am new to stack trading. I want to understand if the stock bought directly from a company via Direct Stock Purchase and is in my Demat account, be sold through another Online Brokerage account I have?
Googling about DSP just tell me about how to bye shares directly from the company but not how these shares can be sold back.